# How can I create a role to create,update,delete stored procedures and views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, role

what permissions do I need to give in order to achieve the above task to get users the capacity to create,update,delete stored procedures and views to a database role.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add a user to the `db_ddladmin` role.

```
-- Older method
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin','username';
-- New method
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER username;
```

This will give the user the ability to create/modify/drop any object in any schema.  Unfortunately that will include objects you probably don't want them to change (tables for example).

A more precise method is to use the `CREATE` permissions.  There is a small trick to using them however.  You will also need to grant `ALTER` on the schema where they can create/alter the objects.  So to grant the ability to create procedures and views in the dbo schema you might do this.

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [UserName];
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [UserName];
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO [UserName];
```

Same with `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE FUNCTION` etc.  The reason you need both is this: `CREATE PROCEDURE` gives you the ability to create the procedure, `ALTER schema` gives you a place to put the procedure as you create it.

I should also point out that the `CREATE` permissions also grant the ability to alter, and drop.

Comment: But giving the ddladmin role will also give rights to the database objects such as tables right, but the right to alter tables should be revoked.

Comment: Correct.  ddladmin gives the ability to modify the structure (but not the data) of a table.  If you don't want to give someone that option I would recommend using the second option.  Grant `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE VIEW` and `ALTER SCHEMA` on dbo (assuming that's the schema you want them to have access too).